# How do the modern companies deploy their app servers?

Tags: web, architecture, amazon-ec2, cloud

I am talking about big companies, like ebay, Amazon. Do they host their application servers on Virtual Machine instances like EC2? Or they are still using physical servers? Is there a trend to move from physical servers to VMs because VMs are cost-effective and scalable?

Thanks!

Update: I found an article here: http://gigaom.com/2012/04/09/why-instagram-is-likely-moving-on-from-amazons-cloud/

Instagram was building on virtual infrastruture before, but its owner FB might be considering to move away from AWS.

But the question still remains: Are the applicaiton still running on virtualized OSes or on native OSes?

Answer (score 0):

HostCabi.net surveys the [top 500 hosting providers](http://hostcabi.net/top_500_hosters) which accounts for the top 100,000 websites excluding the actual top 500 which are surveyed in  the [top 500 websites](http://hostcabi.net/top_500_sites) including who hosts them.

I'm not aware of a specific table that is going to show you what technology each hosting company provides, for that you would have to check on the website of the hosting company to see what service they offer.

Comment: Thanks, norlesh! HostCabi is a good site. I will check the top ones and see what technology they are using.